# Is there any functional difference between Occipital lobe ( in mammals) and Optic lobe (vertebrates other than mammals)?

Tags: evolution, vision, ethology, neuroanatomy, psychology

Visual processing centre in mammals and lower-vertebrates, are known to be different.

In mammals, such as human, it is the **Occipital Lobe** of 2 hemispheres of cerebral cortex; which is a part of **forebrain**. But in more lower groups of vertebrates, it is the **Optic lobe**, which is a part of **midbrain**.

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optic_lobe, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midbrain#Corpora_quadrigemina)

[image: Location of optic lobe]

Image: Placement of optic lobe, Source: http://understanding-vertebrates.weebly.com/nervous-system.html, URL: http://understanding-vertebrates.weebly.com/uploads/3/8/6/8/38682649/8113431_orig.jpg

Now, does this difference cause a difference in how the visual information is processed in their mind? such as which-features of the image extracted, how they are recalled, how they are correlated , joined  etc?

Comment: "Lower vertebrates" is a non-real, anthropocentric concept.

Comment: @kmm I meant non-mammals, and not from anthropocentric view; from evolutionary viewpoint also, "primitive", "advanced" etc are widely used in biology. If you have better terms, you could inform/ edit.

Comment: If a certain species is more "advanced" than some-other species; it doesnot  indicate the first species is more like human being. Rather, an "advanced" may be "inferior" than primitive, due to retrogressive (regressive) evolution. Primitive/Advanced is a phylogenetic concept. Those conserved some older-characteristics with changing time,  are more primitive, those replace old characteristics with new one, with change of time, are advanced.

Comment: @kmm If a plant A is more advanced than plant B; would you tell plant A is more like human being? no. Plant A or B neither are comparable this way because they were evolved in separate route than animals. Rather you could think the more-primitive plant B as quite more similar to human, because it is quite more close to common ancestor.

Comment: @kmm I did not mean a fish is inferior than human, but I meant a fish is evolutionarily primitive (/lower /earlier) than human. And that is ground reality. Terminologies made by us, agree, but the "actual thing"  is real. Wood, Oxygen, Number, Set, 1, 2 , 3, plus, minus, whatever the names are, these scientific terminologies indicate to somethic real.

Comment: @kmm Any suggestion is welcome.